# Copying Paragraph from one document to another and pasting it at the top

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm currently working with Google Apps Script and trying to achieve the following:

1. Have a source document with a paragraph
2. Have a target document
3. Run the function to copy the paragraph from the source documeent into the target document
4. Run the function again to paste new content always at the top of the document, prior to the previous addition.

I've been able to achieve steps 1 to 3 with the following script I came across:

```
function menuItem1() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById('doc id goes here');
  var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren()
  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var body = targetDoc.getBody()
    var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      body.appendParagraph(element);
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      body.appendListItem(element);
      }
    }
  targetDoc.saveAndClose()
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('New template added');
}
```

`

However it always pastes the new content at the bottom of the document. I now understand that this is due to the `appendParagraph` method and that `insertParagraph` is what I should be using. However I'm struggling to understand what index I should be using in order to have my text always paste at the top of the page.

Comment: Child Index 0 is at the very top

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

You can use the [`insertParagraph`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-paragraph) & [`insertListItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertlistitemchildindex,-listitem) methods as seen on this tweaked script below.

Tweaks made:

- Reversed your loop to make sure copied paragraphs are still in order when being inserted to the top of the `target` docs file.
- Used `insertParagraph` instead of `appendParagraph`.
- Used `insertListItem` instead of `appendListItem`.

### Script

```
function menuItem1() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCS ID');
  var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren();
  for (var j = (totalElements - 1); j >= 0; j--) { //Reversed the loop to make sure paragraphs/lists are still in order when inserted to the target sheet.
    var body = targetDoc.getBody()
    var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      body.insertParagraph(0, element); //Always insert at the top
    }
    else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      body.insertListItem(0, element.copy());; //Always insert at the top
    }
  }
  targetDoc.saveAndClose()
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('New template added');
}
```

### Demo

- `source` docs file.

[image]

- After running the script, here's the `target` docs file.

[image]

- When the `source` docs file gets ***updated***.

[image]

- After running the script again, here's the `target` docs file.

[image]

Comment: @NBor94 If we answered your question, you may want to click the up-vote/accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. That way, they'll be easily recommended  to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.